# MySQL Query Hangs

Tags: mysql, sql

This query returns 363 rows in .016 seconds:

```
SELECT
    d.ticker,
    d.price,
    d.dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap,
    d.mocBuyImbalanceSharesSnap,
    d.mocSellImbalanceSharesSnap,
    d.snapShares,
    d.snapValue,
    d.snapDirection
    
FROM
    EODStrategies.t_strat_SinglesFlipSPX1550_Detail d 
WHERE 
    d.runDate = '2020-11-24' 
AND d.event = 'Terminated';
```

This query hangs when I add the line with simple arethmetic:

```
SELECT
    d.ticker,
    d.price,
    d.dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap,
    d.mocBuyImbalanceSharesSnap,
    d.mocSellImbalanceSharesSnap,
    d.snapShares,
    d.dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap + (mocBuyImbalanceSharesSnap - mocSellImbalanceSharesSnap),
    d.snapValue,
    d.snapDirection
    
FROM
    EODStrategies.t_strat_SinglesFlipSPX1550_Detail d 
WHERE 
    d.runDate = '2020-11-24' 
AND d.event = 'Terminated';
```

Why does the second query hang?

Comment: Because something else on your system is either freezing the server or locking the table.

Comment: Why would that table lock specifically when I run the second query?  It's a dev database, I'm the only user on it, nothing else is running.  It's just me firing queries off.  The first one always runs, the second one never does.

Comment: What type are these fields, dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap, mocBuyImbalanceSharesSnap and mocSellImbalanceSharesSnap? What happens if you write the line as "d.dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap + (d.mocBuyImbalanceSharesSnap - d.mocSellImbalanceSharesSnap)"

Comment: dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap is int(11) and  the other two are int(10) unsigned.

If I run it as you suggest, it also hangs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a max column name length issue?

What if you change the line:
d.dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap + (mocBuyImbalanceSharesSnap - mocSellImbalanceSharesSnap),

To:
d.dQuoteImbalanceSharesSnap + (mocBuyImbalanceSharesSnap - mocSellImbalanceSharesSnap) AS math,

Comment: Same result, still hangs. I actually had it that way at first but then removed the "AS math" to see if that would help.